# how to fix "object has no uniform scale"?

Tags: uv

I try to unwrap uv on first ever 3d model i made in blender which is Baymax., then that message shows up in upper right corner of screen. The uv map looks so grotesque. I already tried remove double but nothing changed. 
Help me pls. 
Thanks. 
Im noob at blender btw.

Answer (score 21):

Select the object and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in 'Object Mode'. **Apply the Scale**, then try to unwrap.

You can also see the fragment of Blender Guru's tutorial, where he's talking about it:
https://youtu.be/XCEN0qQOsIA?t=345